# WP7 Propogate exception from BeginGetResponse callback

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, asynccallback

I'm using HttpWebRequest to call a web service. If the AsyncCallback from BeginGetResponse throws an error, I want to propagate it up to my main program flow. I'm having trouble doing this because the error doesn't get propagated beyond the AsyncCallback. I've tried putting try/catch blocks at each step of the HttpWebRequest chain, but it never propagates beyond the "ResponseCallBack" method. Is it possible to get it back to the main thread?

```
private void StartRequest()
{
    // Code to create request object is here
    // ...

    httpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), httpRequest);
}
```

---

```
private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

    // End the operation
    var postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);
    string body = GenerateRequestBody();

    // Convert the string into a byte array
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

    // Write to request stream
    postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    // Start the asynchronous operation to get the resonse
    try
    {
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), request);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

---

```
private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    string contents = String.Empty;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    // Check the status
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //EXCEPTION NEVER MAKES IT PASSED HERE, EVEN IF I HAVE IT IN A TRY/CATCH BLOCK AND RE-THROW IT.
        _object = ProcessResponseEntity(contents);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused about the way asynchronous code exectution works and how the callback execution fits in with the calling code.

Within `GetRequestStreamCallback`, after the call to `request.BeginGetResponse` the method will continue to execute and in your example just end.

It is not known when (or even if) `ResponseCallback` will execute or what will be happening on the UI thread when it does. Because of this, `ResponseCallback` will execute on a different thread.

It's possible to have code within the callback run on the UI thread (which you'll need to do you want to interact with the UI) by using [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=VS.95).aspx). However you can't have this execute within the context of another method.

While I wouldn't recommend it, you may want to have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497874/faking-synchronous-calls-in-silverlight-wp7) on making the callback appear to execute synchronously. This will block your UI thread though and so is NOT recommended.